# play 2 Framework @Messages -> How insert dynamic variable in a same Message?

Tags: variables, internationalization, playframework-2.0, message

I would like insert dynamic variable on my Messages.
For example : `@Messages("social.feed")` work good. 
But I would like have more specific variable :
`@Messages("social.feed.1")`
`@Messages("social.feed.2")`
`@Messages("social.feed.3")`

So i try : `@Messages("social.feed."+@Javavariable)` but this don't compile.
          `@Messages("social.feed.+"@Javavariable")`  compile but write : social.feed.@javavariable

Thank you very much !

Comment: may be you should have tried `@Messages("social.feed."+Javavariable)` without an @ infront of the javavariable.

Answer (score 0):

I found how do it : You have to use javascript adding html for example : $(".interestNameFriend").text(Messages("interestNameFriend."+interestId));